# Strange mktime behaviour - Change if return value is assigned to a variable

Tags: c++, timezone, mktime

I'm experimenting a strange *mktime()* function behaviour. When I assign the value returned by the function, the value of the input parameter is one and when I doesn't the value is different.

I already know that *mktime()* adjust the values of the *struct tm* input parameter but what's happening it's different, lets see the code with the corresponding output:

**First code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct tm cT;
    strptime("31/07/2014 16:54:00", "%d/%m/%Y%n%T", &cT);
    mktime(&cT);

    cout << "Current Time: "  << cT.tm_mday << "/" << cT.tm_mon + 1 << "/" << cT.tm_year + 1900 << " " << cT.tm_hour << ":" << cT.tm_min << ":" << cT.tm_sec << endl;

}
```

**Output:**

> Current Time: 31/7/2014 16:54:0

**Second code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct tm cT;
    strptime("31/07/2014 16:54:00", "%d/%m/%Y%n%T", &cT);
    time_t t = mktime(&cT);

    cout << "Current Time: "  << cT.tm_mday << "/" << cT.tm_mon + 1 << "/" << cT.tm_year + 1900 << " " << cT.tm_hour << ":" << cT.tm_min << ":" << cT.tm_sec << endl;

}
```

**Output:**

> Current Time: 31/7/2014 15:54:0

Any help is welcome. :)

Comment: `time.h` is deprecated. Use `ctime`. Or `chrono`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case of forgetting to initialize a variable. Specifically, you need to initialize the `cT` variable with appropriate values for at least all fields that won't be touched by `strptime` (`strptime` will only set those fields corresponding to the input field descriptors in the format string).

Eg. :

```
struct tm cT = { 0 };
cT.tm_isdst = -1;
strptime("31/07/2014 16:54:00", "%d/%m/%Y%n%T", &cT);
```

Comment: But he is outputting all of the values that strptime() should be filling.  So where is the uninitialized data? The output does not care about tm_isdst.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : `tm_isdst`, which controls whether daylight saving time is in effect. `mktime` will behave differently based on the value of this field. And if it's not initialized, it can have any value.

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now.  `strptime()` does not fill `tm_isdst` but `mktime()` looks at it, so it needs to be initialized manually.

Comment: Great!
I just initialize the variable wit cT = {0} and after that everything was ritgh. Thanks a lot!